# How to break zero index comma separated value into individual string in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to break comma seperated values which are retrieved from database and then put each individual in a string and print it in a for loop only. I am getting the values from database but i am not be able to break values. Below is the code what i have done right till now.Please help to solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

```
$query="select * from create_segment";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die(mysql_error());
$number_of_segment=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $segments[]=$row;
}

foreach($segments as $success) {
 $thePostIdArray = explode(', ', $success['subjects']);
 for($i=0; $i < count($thePostIdArray); $i++)
  {
     echo "string...".$strings=$thePostIdArray[$i];  
  }
}
```

It output:

```
string...1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
string...1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

but i want something like this:

```
for(......)
{
echo "values...".$i;
}
```

which should output

```
values...1
values...2
values...3 and so on.
```

my database structure is like:

```
id    subjects

1     1,2,3,4,5
2     1,2,7
```

Comment: use explode for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use `','` instead of `', '` in your

```
explode(', ', $success['subjects']);
```

statement so it would look like:

```
explode(',', $success['subjects']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
explode(',', $success['subjects'])
```

You had a space after the comma, but there are no spaces in the database values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity to change the database structure you should convert that table into something like this:

```
Id   Subject
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
etc.
```

It will make your queries much easier, and it the right way to go. It will also make it easier for you in the future do join this table with other tables to get the desired results. I know this doesn't answer your questions, but some good advice will never hurt. One of the other answers will answer your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="select * from create_segment";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die(mysql_error());
$number_of_segment=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    foreach (explode(',',$row['subjects']) as $value){
       echo echo "string... {$row['id']} " .  $value . '<br />';
    }
}
```